# Can't create pdf in Lyx

Tags: lyx, miktex

I am a third year math student and I decided to start writing in TEX.

I installed Lyx 2.0 and wrote a new document, when I tried to export using the option "PDF(ps2pdf)" I got an error: `lyx cannot conver file: an error occurred while running python...`

I also have miktex 2.9 installed for Hebrew support.

I tried uninstalling and installing back but that didn't help.

I need some help, any ideas ?

Comment: What do you have in your document?

Comment: Field theory homework...nothing special

Comment: Images, text, language, formatting, styles etc. Hopefully LaTeX shouldn't care about your writing ;)

Comment: A friend compiled it so it should be ok. it's english with math notations and with title\auther..no images. it's basic since it's my first document in lyx

Comment: What does View -> Messages say? What does Document -> LaTeX log say? (best not to paste everything here, just see if does anything interesting)

Comment: Does it work with other documents? E.g. if you create a new file, just write a word and hit Ctrl + R (no need to save), do you get the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use `Export` and "PDF (ps2pdf)".

In the `View` menu and select `View [PDF (pdflatex)]`. You can also use Ctrl+R.

Comment: Another error : "File does not exist". I tried saving again and re-opening the document but I get the same error